# Creating a list of no duplicate string entries in a text file at C#

Tags: c#, linq, io

I'm a beginner at C# programming.
I wanted to create a text file to the desktop in C# Console, which is wanted to add my input new string value to the created text file's new line.
This is my work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace noteonce
{
class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("New Word: ");
        string newWord = Console.ReadLine();
        string wlist = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\list.txt";
        TextWriter inject = new StreamWriter(wlist, true);
        inject.WriteLine(newWord);
        inject.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("New word has been added! ");Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I created the file through the console, but I want each of my entered string to be unique, I did some look up on google but I'm so confused. I want the console to tell me that whether the new input already exists or not, If it is, to warn me as "It already exists! Input another word : ", If it does not exist, just to add it to the list. I need your assistance.

Thank you all for your attention. By the help of Mr.Ankitkumar Bhatt, This is my recent work :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string wlist = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)+@"\list.txt";
        FileStream create = File.Open(wlist, FileMode.Create);
        create.Close();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New Word"+@" ("+(100-i)+") :");
            string newWord = Console.ReadLine();
            string FileContents = File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\list.txt");
            TextWriter inject = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\list.txt", true);
            if (!FileContents.Contains(newWord))
            {
                inject.WriteLine(newWord);
                inject.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It already exists!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                inject.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

But I want to point that, I want the program to recognize all of items in the list, by my last method, it quite works, but when I close, and open the program again, It doesn't give me the warning that New Word is already exist, doesn't add it to the file neither. How can I do the rest ?

Comment: Add the word to a list first. Check the list for that word. If it does not exist in the list, write it to the file, else inform the user

Comment: You have to use two IO-operations here simultaneously, one for reading and one for writing. Thus use a `TextReader` **and** a `TextWriter`.

Comment: Check out [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx). The `Add` method returns true or false on whether it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: @bixarrio . Jess Bridman this won't help him at all! As you see. The program restart for every word added, so how should he be having a list which knows words from last executions,... _HimBromBeere_ 's way is the right one.

Comment: @TripleEEE you are right. I thought of the quickest way without considering the full scope of the code. The other option I had in my head was to check the file instead of a list.

Comment: Regarding your deleted drive, and the deleted question about it, I made this remark: _The first thing to do is to **stop using the drive**. You will need data recovery software to scan the drive and find the files on it. It is not guaranteed you can recover your files but may be possible_. There are free and paid packages to carry out data recovery. If the data was extremely valuable you can pay for people to carry this out for you too.

Comment: As @halfer, said: Stop using the drive. Additional: obtain 2+ additional drives with capacity > problem drive. Onto 1 you will make a copy (ddrescue) of the original drive. Recover files from that drive onto yet another drive. Stack Overflow is not the right place to be asking/talking about doing this (well, partially, as I have written code to do recovery for specific cases). You can look for solutions/questions about this topic on other SE sites (from a user's perspective). I will reassure you that, assuming `sources.list` was not huge, all, or nearly all of your data should be recoverable

Comment: @halfer Thank you all really and sorry for opening off-topic question. I deleted the question. I'll stop trying as you said cuz Im afraid of messing everything up. I found a guide video about rescuing the data through Linux, by testdisk which I found may help. I thought it will generate a file as big as used space in my disk, but when the task was running, got a notification says "your device running out of memory" and stopped at 330~GB dd file even though I didn't use that much space, I think it will generate a whole of 1TB dd file which I can't find any HDD for it and now Im waiting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of "no duplicate" please, have a look at `HashSet<String>`; you may find `TextWriter` and `TextReader` being too complex - try `File.ReadLines()`, `File.AppendAllLines` instead:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
     // better practice is paths combining
     string path = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop, "list.txt");
     // unique (no duplicates) strings so far
     HashSet<String> hash = new HashSet<string>(
       File.ReadLines(path), // file to read from
       StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // let's ignore words' case ("World", "world")

     Console.WriteLine("New Word: ");

     string newWord = Console.ReadLine().Trim(); // let's trim spaces: "world " -> "world"

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newWord)) // let's not add an empty string
       if (!hash.Contains(newWord)) {
         // add new word to the end of file
         File.AppendAllLines(path, new string[] {newWord});

         Console.WriteLine("New word has been added!");
       } 
       else 
         Console.WriteLine("It already exists! Input another word");
     else
       Console.WriteLine("We don't add empty lines."); 

     Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

In case you want to add *several* words, one after one (put an *empty line* to exit):

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
   // better practice is paths combining
   string path = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop, "list.txt");
   // unique (no duplicates) strings so far
   HashSet<String> hash = new HashSet<string>(
     File.ReadLines(path), // file to read from
     StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // let's ignore words' case ("World", "world")

   while (true) {
     Console.WriteLine("New Word: ");

     string newWord = Console.ReadLine().Trim(); // let's trim spaces: "world " -> "world"

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newWord))
       break;

     if (hash.Add(newWord)) {
       File.AppendAllLines(path, new string[] {newWord});

       Console.WriteLine("New word has been added!");
     }
     else 
       Console.WriteLine("It already exists! Input another word.");
   }

   Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Comment: ^^ ... You're like the bartender who serves the right drink before I know myself what to order ;) Nice, but overkill answer to his question :p

Answer (score 2):

before injecting word check the word exists or not like below

```
string FileContents = File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\list.txt");

if (!FileContents.Contains(newWord))
{  
    // Add to file // 
}
```

Comment: This is more ore less the way I would go aswell - maybe if the file is very large, I'd rather use something like `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Filename"))
{
    line.Contains(newWord)
}` this will save you from reading the complete file into memory

Answer (score 1):

1) Read the file and write its content to a `string[]` (Array of string):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(wlist , Encoding.UTF8);
```

2) Read your input and check for duplicates:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();

if (lines.Contains(input)) {
    //Warning message
} else {
    //Success message    
}
```

Comment: can be shortened to `if(lines.Contains(input))` if you're picky like myself.

Comment: @JayGould Thanks for your feedback. You're right. I edited my answer

Comment: `.ToList();` is *redundant* since `File.ReadAllLines` returns array and you can use `Contains()` method of the array itself

Answer (score 1):

this can be accomplished in multiple ways. I will present a solution that most closely will work with your code. There is definitely a more elegant way to accomplish this, but this is a quick and dirty way to accomplish that.

one way is to have a foreach check from your text file so:

```
var isWordPresent = false;
var textLines = File.ReadAllLines(wlist);
foreach (var line in textLines) {
    if (line.contains(newWord) {
        isWordPresent = true;
    }
}
if (isWordPresent == false) {
    inject.WriteLine(newWord);
    inject.Close();
    isWordPresent = false; //added this portion incase you run this code in a while loop 
//so you can reuse it. You would need to have the boolean reset to false
}
```